# Issue trying to Scaffold-DbContext

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

When I attempt to Scaffold-DbContext from MSSQL server I am able to connect just fine, but I'm getting an error about a foreign key in a table that was deleted from the database several weeks ago. The table it is seeing is called ServiceTicket, I have a similar table named ServiceTickets and I've ensured all the foreign keys are set appropriately.

Exact error I'm getting:

```
The foreign key {'ServiceTypeId'} cannot be added to the entity type 'ServiceTicket' because a foreign key on the same properties already exists on entity type 'ServiceTicket' and also targets the key {'ServiceTypeId'} on 'ServiceType'.
```

the table names we actually have in the db are ServiceTickets and ServiceType

[image: Foreign Key Def]

Also I've already tried deleting and re-creating the relationship

Comment: EF is probably pluralizing your table names.

Comment: Post the exact error, the relevant table names, and the foreign key def

Answer (score 1):

After triple checking all the keys there was indeed a second key for the same relationship that was causing the issue.